# Limit problems with another function g(x)

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, limits

How do you go about approaching this problem, when trying to find the limit of g(x). Is it that you check for the limit of g(x) approaching -2 by itself?

the question itself asks " what is the limit of g(x) when x is approaching the given value"

so lim(x->-2) g(-2)=0

[image]

Comment: What is $5-x^2$ for $x=-2$? After finding that it should be easier to argue what must happen with $g(x)$.

Comment: I'll get 1/sqrt(g(x))=0, how do I go about from here finding the limit of g(x)?

Comment: What do you need to divide $1$ with to get $0$?

Comment: I need to divide it by 0 to get 0, So the limit of g(x) is =0, how do I write this in a correct way

Comment: @KevinAbdul, Are you sure correct?

Comment: yes I am sure, 1/0 is =0, or am I doing something wrong here

Comment: Take for example $1/0.001=1000$, so as things get smaller the result gets larger. Look instead what happens as the denominator gets larger in magnitude i.e $1/1000$ or $1/(-1000)$

Comment: when it gets larger then things get smaller, as it gets smaller things get larger. This still makes it hard for me to understand my question.